# AttributeError: module 'glicko2' has no attribute 'Rating'

Tags: python, pycharm

I successfully imported the glicko2 package.
However when I tried to call the Rating function in glicko2, I end up with the below error feedback

"AttributeError: module 'glicko2' has no attribute 'Rating'"

I am very new to python. Can someone please help me out

```
import glicko2 as gl2
gl2.Rating
```

Comment: Is there any chance that you've saved your Python script with the name `glicko2.py`?  If so, rename it to something else.

Comment: My python script is saved with a different name.

Comment: I checked `glicko2` source code and there is no `Rating` class there. Are you sure you didn't confuse it with some other package?